# What to choose for cross-platform and native GUI development

Tags: software-development, gui, user-interface

I am now heading to do some GUI development and after a bit of google-ing I found

1. Qt/Qml for true cross-platform including embedded UI but seems dying and is too vast
2. Electornjs for easy and ready-to-go but is heavy and not native
3. Dart/flutter, with growing communiy, backed by tech gaint and new (which is it's pro as well as con) and not that cross-platform, can't even work with on Linux
4. GTK fast, mature, huge developing community but feels like for more advanced and got messed with C

I will apprecate if this list grows. Can someone recommand me one. What I expect:

1. Native and lightweight
2. Community/support
3. (mainly) Work in (mid-level country in tech field)just started to accelerate towards tech

Comment: What platforms are you targeting?

Comment: @rrirowermainy desktop(windows, linux, mac)

Comment: @SudipGhimire Provide additional details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: You should provide more criteria by which you consider a recommendation successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'll find a product that meets all of your needs.  However, I'd give [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) a look.

Answer (score 0):

## Xojo

[image: Xojo logo]

[Xojo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xojo) is a development environment that includes a visual forms editor, its own object-oriented programming language, and native compilers to build apps for macOS, Windows, and Linux.

The product and company has been around for many years, always improving.